# Writing critique request: the almost imperceptible effects of Zhou Ziwang's injection

Tags: writing-critique

Continuing from parts [1](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35746/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-and-the-revolutionary-new-technology), [2](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35763/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-was-fat-when-she-was-young), [3](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35780/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwangs-father-takes-her-to-the-doctor), and [4](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35870/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-gets-an-injection-from-the-doctor):

> 一周过去了但没有任何效果，我还是很胖。在做日常活动的过程中，我渐渐忘了那个神秘的医生和他的注射器。再一周过去了，我的行为几乎感觉不到任何变化，我还真想吃巧克力和其他的垃圾食品。其实当时那支注射器有[意外](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%84%8F%E5%A4%96)甚至[不易察觉](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%8D%E6%98%93%E5%AF%9F%E8%A7%89)的影响，不过到现在我还不知道如何清楚的解释这样的感觉。我想吃巧克时，身体似乎自动地[反应](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%8F%8D%E5%BA%94)，而连吃巧克力以前我都感觉到很满意。这是我现在的解释，可是肯定是不准确的。

Please critique my writing. New words for me are in links. I'm at an "almost mastered HSK4" level.

The narrative is from a person in the present (Zhou Ziwang 周子望) describing her unusual past.

I know I got [效果 wrong previously](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/35747/8099), but I think it's okay here.  [I know I'm bad at 了ing](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35990/how-does-someone-train-using-%E4%BA%86-correctly), but I don't see any problems here (which probably means there's many).

Answer (score 1):

Other than little wordy, and sometimes choosing less effective words, there's no major mistake in this piece.

Suggestions:

- 其实当时那支注射器有意外甚至不易察觉的影响 (*ambiguous word: 意外 can also means "accidental". If you meant 'surprising' or "unexpected", it should be "意料之外" or "意想不到"* ) --> 其实当时那支注射器(对我)有意想不到，甚至不易察觉的影响 ( *add '对我' to identify the object that's being effected is 'me', or else we don't know if it is effecting the world or the future*)
- 在做日常活动的过程中 (*wordy*) -->在日常活动的時候
- 我的行为几乎感觉不到任何变化 (*wordy*)-->我的行为几乎沒有任何变化
- 不过到现在我还不知道如何清楚的解释这样的感觉。 (*used adjective when it should be an adverb*) --> 但到现在，我还不知道如何清楚(地)解释这样的感觉
- 我想吃巧克时，身体似乎自动地反应 (*missing the modal verb 'would'(會)*)--> 我想吃巧克时，身体似乎(會)自动地反应
- 而连吃巧克力以前我都感觉到很满意 (*less effective word: '而连' (and even) should be replaced by a stand alone common word '甚至') ; (ambiguous word: '以前' can also mean 'previously' If you meant 'before' it should be 之前 or simply 前) and missing the modal verb 'would'(會)*) --> (甚至在)吃巧克力前我都(會)感觉到很满意
- 这是我现在的解释，可是肯定是不准确的。(*less effective word, '准确' mainly means accurate/ precise, for the meaning of 'correct' it is better to use '正确'* ) --> 这是我现在的解释，可是肯定是不正确的。

Overall you've done a good job.

*PS. Try to avoid run on sentence. You can break a long sentence up with commas, like in my suggestion here 不过到现在我还不知道如何清楚的解释这样的感觉 --> 但到现在，我还不知道如何清楚(地)解释这样的感觉 Just like taking a short pause in speech*

Answer (score 1):

Since you have quite much knowledge of Chinese, I will write my answer in Chinese for accurately expressing my ideas.

最小修改:

一周过去了，但没有任何效果，我还是很胖。日常**生活**中，我渐渐忘了那个神秘的医生和他的注射器。又一周过去了，我的**爱好**几乎没有**可感**的变化：我还是**特别**想吃巧克力和其他垃圾食品。其实，当时的**注射**有不易察觉**但**令人意外的影响，不过到现在我还**是**不知道如何清楚**地**解释它。我想吃巧克力时，身体似乎自动**作出**反应，（使我在吃到巧克力以前就能感到**满足**了）。这是我现在的解释，可是肯定是不准确的。

活动作为名词，一般指多人参与的有组织、有目的行动，如班团活动、党建活动、促销活动、敌后活动。日常活动似有不妥，宜易作日常生活。

行为是人能动性的外在表现，所以我想吃巧克力等不是行为，应当换成其他跟想法有关的词语。另外，我的行为并不是有思想主体，不能感觉，所以应该用可感。（似乎与“这件衣服感觉不错”矛盾，但是此例中可以将感觉理解为“给人的感觉”这一名词性成分；但“感觉不到”这样的说法显然是作动词用的。）

这样的真一般用在感叹语境下：这可真行呀！你真棒！它并不表示really之类的意思。所以应该换成特别一类的词。

是注射这项操作而不是注射器这件器物对我有影响。

“意外甚至不易察觉”的递进关系不明，不宜用甚至一词。转折关系的但比较合适

“还不”与“还是不”有什么区别？“还是不”强调了主观探求但未成功的含义。试比较：

你们俩瞒得可好，我之前还不知道欠了那么多钱呢！（不可以用“还是不”，此前完全不知道欠钱这回事。）

你们俩瞒得可好，我现在还是不知道欠了多少钱。（不可以用“还不”，此处我探求过到底欠了多少钱，但未成功。）

材料换过许多次了，还是不能用。（不可以用“还不”。）

材料刚送去试验，应该还不能用。（不可以用“还是不”。）

此处周子望应该认真考虑过药物的影响到底是什么，所以用“还是不”。

的换成地。

此前的主题是影响，何故同一句中变成了解释这种“感觉”？用指示代词就可以了。

作出反应是更好的搭配。

（）一句我不太确定想表达的意思，但是似乎这种“时态”或“逻辑”复杂一点的句子题主处理得很不好。

生物学意义上，食物给人以满足，而不是满意的感受。